# Create an event with insert into

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE myT(
    p1  float(6,2),
    p2  float(6,2),
    p3  float(6,2),
    date timestamp not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    primary key(date)
);
```

I create this event:

```
CREATE EVENT insert_new ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
   INSERT INTO myT(p1,p2,p3, date) VALUES (1.00,2.00,3.00, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

With this event I expect that every minute MySQL insert automatically e new record
with the timestamp as primary key. But this event doesn't work

Comment: What are p1,p2,p3? Why isn't there a p4?

Comment: They are only variables, this is only a test table

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT insert_new 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
   STARTS  '2014-10-03 00:00:00'
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
    insert into myT(p1,p2,p3, date)
    values(1.00,2.00,3.00, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
//
```